# error firebase and angularfire in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I installed firebase and angularfire with bower bower.

I included the files and angularfire but I get these errors:

[image]

When I click error on the file angularfire

[image]

code app.js

```
          var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ionic','firebase'])

      .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

            // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
            // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
            // a much nicer keyboard experience.
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
          }
          if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
          }
        });
      })

      app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state("home",{ url : "/home", templateUrl : "templates/home.html" , controller: "HomeCtrl"});
        $stateProvider.state("Inscription",{ url : "/inscription", templateUrl : "templates/inscription.html" , controller: "InscriCtrl"});
        $stateProvider.state("listmsg",{ url : "/listmsg", templateUrl : "templates/list.html" , controller: "ListCtrl"});
        $stateProvider.state("msg",{ url : "/msg", templateUrl : "templates/msg.html" , controller: "MsgCtrl"});

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");
      }]);


      app.controller('HomeCtrl', [,'$firebaseSimpleLogin',function($scope,$firebaseSimpleLogin) {

        var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://appsfactor-68466.firebaseio.com");
        var loginObj = $firebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseObj);

        $scope.SignIn = function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();  // To prevent form refresh
          var username = $scope.user.email;
          var password = $scope.user.password;

          loginObj.$login('password', {
              email: username,
              password: password
            })
            .then(function(user) {
              // Success callback
              console.log('Authentication successful');
            }, function(error) {
              // Failure callback
              console.log('Authentication failure');
            });
        }


      }]);


      app.controller('InscriCtrl', [function() {

      }]);

      app.controller('ListCtrl', [function() {

      }]);

      app.controller('MsgCtrl', [function() {

      }]);
```

code index.html

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
      <title></title>

      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

      <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
      <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
            .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
            .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
        }
      </script>-->

      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

      <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">
      <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

              <!-- AngularFiionic servere -->
      <script src="lib/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
      <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
          apiKey: "myapi",
          authDomain: "appsfactor-68466.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://appsfactor-68466.firebaseio.com/",
          storageBucket: "gs://appsfactor-68466.appspot.com",
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
      </script>
      <script src="lib/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>



      <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
      <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
      -->

      <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
      <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

      <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
      <script src="cordova.js"></script>

      <!-- your app's js -->
      <script src="js/app.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

    <ion-side-menus>

      <ion-side-menu-content>


          <ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm">
            <ion-nav-buttons>
                <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon ion-navicon">

                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
          </ion-nav-bar>

          <ion-nav-view>

          </ion-nav-view>

      </ion-side-menu-content>

          <ion-side-menu side="left">

            <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="home">Acceuil</ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="Inscription">Inscription</ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="listmsg">Listes Messages</ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="msg">Message</ion-item>

          </ion-side-menu>

      </ion-side-menus>



    </body>
  </html>
```